# Is a transit visa required for airport terminal change in Dubai?

Tags: visas, transit, dxb

I would like to travel to [Qeshm Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qeshm) (free zone area in Iran) via Dubai Airport.

At Dubai Airport I arrive at terminal 1, and my flight to Qeshm leaves from terminal 3.

How can I pass from Terminal 1 to Terminal 3? Will I require a transit visa?

Comment: You can walk air-side between the terminals, but visa requirements will depend on your citizenship - what passport will you be travelling with?

Comment: indian passport

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a transit visa. You can walk from Terminal 1 to Terminal 3.

---

- Terminal 1 is the original airport terminal, which is for all international airlines.
- Terminal 2 is for low-cost airlines and other operators.
- Terminal 3 is dedicated for Emirates and Qantas, and there is a separate building (part of Terminal 3) which is dedicated for the A380. To get to these gates, you need to take the airport train from Terminal 3 - in the picture, this is the building labeled "A-Gates".

As you can see from the image - T1 and T3 are joined by a walkway, and the Airbus terminal is joined by a train.

Terminal 2 is the terminal you have to worry about. There are very few flights that connect from this terminal, to airlines flying out of the other two terminals. The only exception that I know of is FlyDubai which has some flights that are transiting on Emirates.

To get from that Terminal 2 to Terminal 1 or Terminal 3, you need either a connecting flight (in which case, you will be taken by a special bus) or you need to have a transit visa.

[image]

Comment: i heard the freezone area (qeshm island )  not required any visa for 12 days visit. so can i get imigration from terminal 3 . i didnt get any special visa to qeshm island

Comment: From what I know, visa free stay is limited to 14 days; but its best for you to ask this as a separate question. This question is about visa for transit in Dubai.