# Is a visa required for Qeshm island in Iran?

Tags: indian-citizens, visa-free-entry, iran, islands

I would like to know if the [Qeshm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qeshm) freezone area requires a visa for a 14 day visit.

I didn't try to get any type of visa to Qeshm island; and I hold an Indian passport.

Comment: I don't know why you keep asking about _"immigration from terminal 2 or 3"_. You said in your [previous question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71754/is-a-transit-visa-required-for-airport-terminal-change-in-dubai) you were arriving on terminal 1, and departing from terminal 3.

Comment: Sir, i want to go qeshm island on next week. my father and all family is an iranian cityzen. this is the first time i am trying from saudi arbia to travel to qeshm. so what i will do. i want to travel from jeddah air port. to qeshm. there no any direct flight or connection flight. what i will do please help me

Comment: Are you Iranian citizen as well? If so, you do not need a visa to go to Qeshm island. No matter what your nationality, you **do not need a visa to transit in Dubai Airport** since you are not leaving the terminal building.

Answer (score 9):

According to [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=ir&SECTION=vi&SUBSECTION=vs&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), the database used by airlines:

> Visa exemptions:
>
> - Passengers arriving at Kish (KIH) and Qeshm (GSM) islands
>     for a maximum stay of 14 days.
>
>   - This does **not** apply to nationals of Afghanistan, Bangladesh, Canada, Colombia, **India**, Iraq, Jordan, Nepal,
>       Pakistan, Somalia, Sri Lanka and USA.

While many sources indicate that the 14-day visa exemptions for Qeshm applies to **all** nationalities, airlines go by Timatic and would probably deny you boarding without a visa.

Furthermore, according to the travel agency 1stQuest:

> The problem is Iran MFA rules are changing all the time, **one day they ask for visa in Qeshm and one day they don't**. That's why we do not recommend any Indian citizen to travel Qeshm and Kish without visa and guide until they're confident about visa rules

Answer (score 7):

## Edit: I trust [the answer by @Crazydre](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/84512/32134) more than mine, suggesting you get a visa!

**Old answer of mine:**
I can find [many](http://www.qeshmtravels.com/help.php) - [different](http://askaboutiran.com/business/free-zone/qeshm) - [sources](http://www.qeshmairport.ir/main/en/page,16001) - [that](http://www.irna.ir/en/News/81317422/) - [Qeshm](http://www.muscatdaily.com/Archive/Oman/Visa-free-ferry-service-from-Khasab-to-Qeshm-Island-to-be-launched-soon-4l0a) - [is](http://en.farsnews.com/newstext.aspx?nn=13930628000296) - [visa-free](https://www.regaltoursuae.com/Qeshm-Package) for up to 14 days visits.

All of those sources by themselves look kind of fishy and I would not trust a visa issue on them, but seen together and given that such reputable sources as the airport of Qeshm and the Iranian News Agency are among them, I am almost convinced.

Apparently you have to enter Qeshm directly (i.e. not via Iran mainland), e.g. via flights from Dubai or a soon-to-be-operating ferry from Oman and a deposit is needed according to the first link.
Also check if you need a visa for Dubai!

Answer (score 1):

Most Nationalities are eligible to travel Kish and Qeshm Island without visa for 14 days. Exceptions are nationals of Afghanistan, Bangladesh, Canada, Colombia, India, Iraq, Jordan, Nepal, Pakistan, Somalia, Sri Lanka and USA.

You need to take a direct flight from overseas to these islands, like you can take a direct flight from Dubai to Kish and Qeshm, which means visa-free is available only if you enter these islands from international airports.

Comment: While this answer provides useful information (such as need for direct flight), please be sure to add links to relevant sources. Also it is a good idea to disclose your affiliations to any linked sites so that your answer does not get marked as spam. I have edited the answer to add that affiliation (by looking at the site and your account name).